# Splitting data based on row values based on conditions

Tags: r, split, plyr, subset

this is how my data looks like:

```
df <- structure(list(`1` = c(1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5  ,6 , 7 , 8 , 9, 10 ,11 ,12, 13, 14 ,15 ,16, 17, 18), `2` = structure(c(4L,5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 6L,4L,5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 6L,4L,5L),  .Label=c("a","a","b","b","b","c","c","b","b","b","e","e","f","g","g","g","f","f"),
class="factor"),`3`=c(1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0),`4`=c(0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1), `5` =c(10,5,20,20,5,0,0,10,10,5,10,5,15,5,5,5,2,2)),
 .Names = c("N", "Condition", "AOI_hit_b", "AOI_hit_f", "Time"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18"))
```

I now want to make calculations on Time, depending on whether `Condition` `b` is preceded by `a` or `c` - depending on wheter `AOI_hit_b` is a `0` or `1`. To that comes that only the first hit of `1` in a `Condition` is relevant for time, as it always writes the same time for multiple `1`'s in a condition. 
I tried it with the ddply package, but didn't get the output I wanted.
My output should look something like this:

```
sum of 
Condition Time
b(a)       25
b(c)       10
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
hit_cb = list()
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
    if (df[i,2] == "b") & (df[i-1,2] == "c") {
        hit_cb[i] = ddply(df,.(AOI_hit_b), summarize, mysum=sum(unique(Time)))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for supplying data. I would like to see any code you have also. Beyond that, I don't understand this part of your question: `depending on whether Condition b is preceded by a or c - depending on wheter AOI_hit_b is a 0 or 1.` Is that "(IF previous row of Condition == a OR previous row of Condition == c) AND AOI_hit_b == 1 THEN do something to Time"? How do you want Time to change? Do you add 1 to it or...?

Comment: Hi @SlowLearner, thanks a lot for answering! This is my code so far: hit_cb = list()

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  if (df[i,2] == "b") & (df[i-1,2] == "c"){
 
    hit_cb[i] = ddply(df,.(AOI_hit_b), summarize, mysum=sum(unique(Time)))
  }}. I meant IF previous row of Condition == than sum up Time, but only IF AOI_hit_b == 1. Sorry for being not precise! Best, Angelika

Comment: Please use the edit button to add the code to your question and format using the code button on the editing toolbar.

Comment: Thanks for telling me, sorry I'm new to here1

Comment: Seems like you're missing parentheses in `if (df[i,2] == "b") & (df[i-1,2] == "c")`.